# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'applicantid')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a login request (req, res functions).

I already printed out the params in server.js and it worked perfectly, but there's a problem sending it to the function in human resources.js. The params are just "undefined" once its passed on. Everything is imported and working correctly, these are just code snippets from the class. Thank you so much

Code (server.js):

```js
app.post('/dologin', (req, res) => {

    humanresources.login(req.body).then((result) => {
        console.log("result", result);
        res.send(result);
    });
    
});
```

Code (human resources.js):

```js
function login(req, res) {

    // params: { applicantid, password }

    let params = req.body;
    let applicantid = params.applicantid;
    let password = params.password;
    
    client.connect(err => {

        if (err) {
            return "Error connecting to database";
        }

        collectionApplicants.findOne({_id: applicantid}, function(error, user) {
            console.log('move on 2');
            if (user == (undefined || null) || error) {
                return res.json("An employee account couldn't be returned with the given crednetials, please try again");

            } else {

                comparePassword(password, user.password).then((compared) => {

                    if (compared != "Passwords match!") {

                        return res.response(compared);

                    } else {

                        // configure last signed in date to todays date & current time
                        var today = new Date();
                        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
                        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0"); //January is 0!
                        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                        today = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
                        today = new Date(today);

                        // update last online date
                        collectionApplicants.updateOne({_id: user._id}, {$set: {lastOnline: today}}, function(err, result) {

                            client.close();
                            if (err) {

                                return res.status(400).json("Error updating last online date");

                            } else {

                                return res.status(200).json("Successfully logged in as " + user.firstName + " " + user.lastName);

                            }

                        });

                    }

                }).catch((error) => {

                    console.log(error);
                    return res.status(400).json("Error comparing password, please try again");

                });

            }

        });

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing req.body in your server.js , but in login function you are trying to read req.body again

Your login function can be

```
function login(params) {

    // params: { applicantid, password }

    // let params = req.body
    let applicantid = params.applicantid;
    let password = params.password;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This fixed it. Now I have a problem returning "res.json".

Comment: the new function is function login(params, res) and it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError TypeError: res.json is not a function